# NavigationExperimental Header cuts off top of AnimatedView scenes

Tags: navigation, react-native

In react-native's NavigationExperimental, the AnimatedView's Header is rendered as an overlay.

This means that any scenes that are rendered by the animated view have their tops cut off by the header.

What's the best way to prevent the tops of my scenes from being cut off?  I can add padding to the top of every scene, but that seems like a hack.

Answer (score 1):

`AnimatedView` is due to be deprecated int he next release. You can use `NavigationTransitioner` instead.

`NavigationTransitioner` receive only one render prop called `render`, unlike  `AnimatedView` that had `renderScene` and `renderOverlay`, so now you should render your header as part of your scene. That will solve the issue that you reported.

See [this post](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7210) for more information.